# Connecting to a mongodb server running on a remote desktop windows

Tags: mongodb, remote-access

I have another PC at my home address (windows) which I use for a lot of my data processing. I use `Remote Desktop Connection` to connect to that PC (IP 123.456.789.00) where I have a mongodb server running. I want to connect to that mongo server on my laptop (windows). So far I have tried following [several instructions](https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/mongodb-auth/) but I am struggling to connect. So far I have tried setting up the user:

```
db.createUser({
    user: 'ian',
    pwd: 'secretPassword',
    roles: [{ role: 'readWrite', db:'cool_db'}]
})
```

Then edited the .cfg file:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  bindIp : 0.0.0.0
  port: 27017
  
#processManagement:

security:
  authorization: 'enabled'
```

I believe I have opened up port `27017` following these [instructions](https://www.tomshardware.com/uk/news/how-to-open-firewall-ports-in-windows-10,36451.html).

I have restarted mongo server on my pc at home.

Then I have tried logging in via mongo compass on my laptop but I can't connect:

[image]

Comment: Try using `admin` as the authentication database.

Comment: No luck @Joe, I can log in to the database through localhost on the remote PC using `cool_db` as the authentication db

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I fixed my problem. Although I had opened the port on my PC's firewall, I had not opened it on the router. I logged in to my home router > firewall rules > add inbound > opened port 27017 within the port forwarding tab.